# Fatal erro in POST using request module Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm working on a web scraper build in python. Until now I build the following code:
import requests

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'truegamedata.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'sec-gpc': '1',
    'origin': 'https://truegamedata.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://truegamedata.com/weapon_builder.php',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

data = {
  'weapon_name': '^%^5B^%^22Kilo 141^%^22^%^2C^%^22wz^%^22^%^5D'
}

response = requests.post('https://truegamedata.com/SQL_calls/base_data.php', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.text)
```

For some reason, I get the following error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in /home/customer/www/truegamedata.com/public_html/SQL_calls/base_data.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/customer/www/truegamedata.com/public_html/SQL_calls/base_data.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And how I can get this response?

Here is the request from Chorme Dev tools:

```
Request URL: https://truegamedata.com/SQL_calls/base_data.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:61696
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 12 Feb 2021 20:08:45 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
host-header: 8441280b0c35cbc1147f8ba998a563a7
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-httpd-modphp: 1
x-proxy-cache-info: DT:1
:authority: truegamedata.com
:method: POST
:path: /SQL_calls/base_data.php
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9
content-length: 42
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: PHPSESSID=375e8ebdfa9174d6db5eb8c1cda4411b; game=wz
origin: https://truegamedata.com
referer: https://truegamedata.com/weapon_builder.php
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-gpc: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
weapon_name: ["FR 5.56","wz"]
```

I tried to give as much information as possible, if anything is missing let me know